# Django migration fails for ForeignKey to custom user model

Tags: django, django-1.7, django-migrations

When I run a migration for a new model that has a ForeignKey to a custom User model, I get an error:

```
ValueError: Lookup failed for model referenced by field test.TestModel.user: account.EmailUser
```

It's in Django 1.7.

My custom user is `apps.models.EmailUser`.

Here's the relevant code:

```
# apps.test/models.py
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings


class TestModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

# settings.py

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'account.EmailUser'
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'apps.account',
    'apps.test',
)
```

Finally, here's the migration file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models, migrations
from django.conf import settings


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='TestModel',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID', serialize=False, auto_created=True, primary_key=True)),
                ('user', models.ForeignKey(to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
            ],
            options={
            },
            bases=(models.Model,),
        ),
    ]
```

### Full error traceback

```
Running migrations:
  Applying test.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 4, in <module>
    manage_environment()
  File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/lingoing/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bobsleigh/runner/__init__.py", line 9, in manage_environment
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/lingoing/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/lingoing/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/lingoing/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/lingoing/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/lingoing/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 160, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=options.get("fake", False))
  File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/lingoing/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 63, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(migration, fake=fake)
  File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/lingoing/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 91, in apply_migration
    if self.detect_soft_applied(migration):
  File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/lingoing/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 135, in detect_soft_applied
    apps = project_state.render()
  File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/lingoing/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 89, in render
    model=lookup_model,
ValueError: Lookup failed for model referenced by field test.TestModel.user: account.EmailUser
```

### Extra info

I notice that there is a test to see if it's using a custom user model in django.db.migrations.state.render(), but it only takes this test seriously if render is called with ignore_swappable=True, which it isn't in my case.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: have you done *any* migrations before substituting the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` to a custom version? Because if so, then you probably need to fix your schema manually, see the warnings in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model).

Comment: Ah, that fixed it!  I was aware of that documentation and had run the migrations after emptying the database.  But I neglected to delete all the migration files before remaking them!  I dropped all tables on the database, deleted all the migration files, ran makemigrations and now migration works.  Thanks!